# Probability and expectation of an indicator multiplied by random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

Could you advice me on the following inequality

$P(|Z_n\mathbb{1}_{|Z_n|<n^{0.75}}|>\epsilon)\le P(|Z_n|<n^{0.75})$

and equality

$E(Z_n^2)E(\mathbb{1}^2_{|Z_n|\ge n^{0.75}})=P(|Z_n|\ge n^{0.75})$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $Z_n = 0$ happens infrequently, the first inequality has a positive LHS when the indicator is 1 (then $P[|Z_n| > \epsilon] \le 1$).

For the second one you have for any event $A$: $$\mathbb{E}[1^2_A] = \mathbb{E}[1_A] = \mathbb{P}[A]$$ and apparently we are assuming $\mathbb{E}[Z_n^2] = 1$.

Comment: thanks @gt6968b for help. The second point I got it but the first one is unclear to me.